# update subcollection field in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a firestore collection and want to update a couple fields in it's subcollection, which is in the form of an array. I cannot manage to do this. the data parameter gets me exactly what I want, and then i slice it to get the last array in subcollection. Have broken it down to collection('').doc('').collection(''), as well, with no luck. Thank you for any help!

```
async updateDialogueStatus({ state }, data){
    const whoDis =  this.$fire.auth.currentUser
    if (data.dialogue.length > 0) {
      const lastDialogueInArray = data.dialogue.slice(-1)[0];
      this.$fire.firestore.collection('conversations/' + data.id + 'dialogue/' + lastDialogueInArray.messageId).update({
           status: "read",
           readBy: whoDis.email
      })
    } else {}
```

i get this error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.$fire.firestore.collection(...).update is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing a path to the document to update, but then call `this.$fire.firestore.collection`. Call `.doc` to get the correct object, on which you can call `update`.

```
//                                                   
this.$fire.firestore.doc('conversations/' + data.id + '/dialogue/' + lastDialogueInArray.messageId).update({
```

Comment: thanks Frank! but i now get this error: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but conversations/Euawxq9p2sjJFqO7dk7kdialogue/4641227046-4d3fd313-250e-4a09-808f-aa86597a67bb has 3.

Comment: and when i do '/dialogue/' i get: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/foo-79b43/databases/(default)/documents/conversations/Euawxq9p2sjJFqO7dk7k/dialogue/4641227046-4d3fd313-250e-4a09-808f-aa86597a67bb

Comment: 10 You were missing a `/`, see the second  that I added in my answer. 2) So it sounds like the document doesn't exist. If you want to create a new document, use `set` instead of `update`.

Comment: thank you @Frank! now to figure out why it doesn't exist.